# How to install gem pg on snow leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

I need to install gem pg on snow leopard because I am running rake on rails codebase. I am not using postgres.

This is the error I am getting.

```
$ sudo gem install pg
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

looked at various blogs from google search but none of them work.

Answer (score 9):

You may have to specify your CPU architecture. First, run the following to see which architecture you're running on:

(Note: Replace '/usr/bin/ruby' with whatever 'which ruby' returns).

```
$ lipo -detailed_info /usr/bin/ruby
```

In there, you should see something about your architecture (look for 'i386' or 'x86_64')

If that doesn't work, try the following:

```
$ irb
['foo'].pack('p').size
```

The result will be '8' if Ruby is running as 64-bit, or '4' if it's running in 32-bit.

Then, when you go to install the Postgres gem, specify the appropriate architecture:

```
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install pg
```

Or,

```
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

If you're running Snow Leopard with a 64-bit CPU, then you're *probably* running the 64-bit version. **But still be sure to double-check your architecture,** otherwise it probably won't work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to actually build and install Postgres before you can build a Ruby adaptor for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using Postgres, you shouldn't need to install the driver - you only need the driver for the database you are using.