# Yet another "installing pg gem" issue on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, bundle, pg

So, I've just spent the best part of the day trying to get Rails (and required gems) to install correctly.

After hours with line cache and nokogiri I'm just starting to feel drained and have now come up with a problem installing the 'pg' gem.

I'm going to continue battling on but any advice here with this problem?

(And I know I shouldn't ask two questions in 1 SO post but I'm going to anyway. I've installed vast amounts of software in the past (including compiling Linux kernels from scratch) and Rails seems inordinately difficult to install on Snow Leopard. On a par with getting Linux display drivers working in the bad old days. Is there any progress being made anywhere on making this process simpler?)

Error log is:

```
Using linecache19 (0.5.12) 
Installing nokogiri (1.5.0) with native extensions 
Installing pg (0.12.2) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... yes
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0 -I/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I/Users/user/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/include -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe  -o compat.o -c compat.c
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0 -I/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I/Users/user/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/include -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe  -o pg.o -c pg.c
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_exec’:
pg.c:954: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:993: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_prepare’:
pg.c:1059: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_exec_prepared’:
pg.c:1150: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1180: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_s_escape’:
pg.c:1324: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1331: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_send_query’:
pg.c:1504: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1543: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_send_prepare’:
pg.c:1608: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_send_query_prepared’:
pg.c:1697: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1728: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_wait_for_notify’:
pg.c:2103: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_put_copy_data’:
pg.c:2173: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_block’:
pg.c:2586: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:2592: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
pg.c:2607: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_locreate’:
pg.c:2870: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘find_or_create_johab’:
pg.c:3940: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c:3946: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_get_client_encoding_as_rb_encoding’:
pg.c:3974: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_get_rb_encoding_as_pg_encname’:
pg.c:4006: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_internal_encoding_set’:
pg.c:4065: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_external_encoding’:
pg.c:4121: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle -o pg_ext.bundle compat.o pg.o -L. -L/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib -L/Users/user/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lruby.1.9.1 -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/pg-0.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/pg-0.12.2/ext/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing pg (0.12.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.12.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any progress being made anywhere on making this process simpler?)

Yes: Yehuda Katz is leading a Kickstarter project to help:
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1397300529/railsapp

Looks like you may have an old openssl.

Try this:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

View the list of outdated ports:

```
port outdated
```

Clean up outdated ports:

```
sudo port clean outdated
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

See if you have any libssl:

```
find / | grep libssl.*dylib
```

Try installing postgresql from a Mac download:

```
http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/
```

Then try installing the gem as usual:

```
gem install pg
```

Or if you use sudo do:

```
sudo gem install pg
```

Comment: Thank goodness for that. Many kudos to Katz for 1. identifying the problem and 2. taking it on. Not sure this answers my original question as I don't use ports (or fink) but my fault for asking 2 questions - hence the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is a 64bit/32bit issue resp. a mismatch between your ruby version and your Postgresql Installation.
Depending on your architecture you have to make use of the correct ARCH flags.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656562/how-to-install-gem-pg-on-snow-leopard/2680108#2680108) on stackoverflow.

Generally I have little to no problems using "[homebrew](https://brew.sh/)" and [RVM](https://rvm.io)

HTH